# Who owns the workspace created by queueing a build in TFS

Tags: tfs

When I deleted the build definition, it did not delete a workspace it created.  And with a new build definition, it's complaining that the project is already mapped to another location from the deleted build definition.

When I list my workspaces, it is not there.  Who is the owner of this dynamically generated workspace and how can I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Build Service account owns that workspace.  You can use the (free) tool TFS Sidekicks to find and delete any workspace by any user in a nice GUI: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/